# when we need to compaction in Cassandra?

Tags: database, cassandra, nosql

if we have a system that doesn't have any update or delete records and all inserts partitioned by size (100Mb).
needs system still to compaction for increase performance?

Comment: how the primary key looks like for the biggest table?

Comment: By default, minor compaction is running. If all okay don't require major compation.

Comment: @AlexOtt Our Primary key is ((month, Buck_id), UUID) example ["2021-01", 1 , <uuid>] partitioning (mont,buck_id) we use them for bucketing permonth and per 100MB.